# Update manager showing some softwares having .exe format!

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

Today I was updating my softwares via `Update Manger`. After completing the downloads, while these softwares were installing, I've found that some softwares have .exe format! I can't figure this out! Can somebody explain me what is actually happening here???[image: Linux Software having .exe format]

Comment: AFAIK, Ubuntu doesn't actually execute these files. It extracts the embedded TrueType fonts and deletes the `.exe` afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these are Smart package of Microsoft's core fonts downloaded by  `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` .

Description of publisher on **sourceforge** Site :

So far this project consists of a source rpm that can be used to easily create a binary rpm package that, when installed, gives access to Microsoft's TrueType core fonts for the Web.

Link of project : [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/)

Comment: But how Linux can recognize .exe format?

Comment: It is only a name

Comment: you can name a file what you want in linux

Comment: that doesn't means it like a windows exe file

Answer (score 2):

The ttf-mscorefonts-installer downloads those .exe files. This installer is used to install Microsoft TrueType core fonts in Ubuntu.

Those fonts are available on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/) as executable cabinet file which use the .exe extension.